# preg_replace "gotcha" with replacement value escaping

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm running a preg_replace on content that I don't necessarily control and I'm running into an issue with replacement values containing things like currency values (i.e. `$1.00`).  Admittedly this is a common problem that's been addressed in other questions.  The closest solution I've found is:

http://www.procata.com/blog/archives/2005/11/13/two-preg_replace-escaping-gotchas/

My problem is more complicated because the replacement value is not something I can escape ahead of time, at least not in a way I can see.  Here's my preg code:

```
$body = preg_replace('/<special_tag id="'.$tagID.'">(.*?)<\/special_tag>/','$1',$body);
```

As you can see I'm capturing all content within a set custom tag, and removing the surrounding opening and closing tags, but keeping the content found inside.  The replacement `'$1'` however doesn't lend itself to the escaping that is required, and so currency values that happen to be in the replacement values are getting terminated incorrectly.

Have I over thought this replacement?  Is there something else I can use to remove my special tags keeping in mind that it must take into account the unique ID for that specific tag?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Is there something else I can use to remove my special tags": uuuh, [how about a DOM parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)?

Comment: I actually used that method in another part of the same script but it seemed overkill for this particular replacement, just trying to keep overhead down if I can, but if this is the only option, I will fall back on it.

Comment: it's not the *only* option, but it comes to (my) mind before approaching this with Regex.

Comment: @Gordon Seems the DOM is the preferred method, thanks for your input! I imagine I can rewrite my current stuff to use it more efficiently :) Since there are no other answers, if you're willing, can you create one with the same link for others, and I'll accept it.

Comment: procata.com's solution is incomplete.  The string $replacement = '$10+\\5' will not be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible DOM solution that shouldn't have any of the "gotchas".

Assuming this HTML:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<html>
    <body>
        <special_tag id="foo">
            <p>Some content</p>
            <p>Some more content</p>
        </special_tag>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;
```

You pull up the children of special_tag and remove special_tag afterwards:

```
// create DOMDocument, suppress parsing errors
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

// get special_tag with id foo
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$foo = $xpath->query('//special_tag[@id="foo"]')->item(0);

// move all children before special_tag
while ($foo->childNodes->length > 0) {
    $foo->parentNode->insertBefore($foo->childNodes->item(0));
}

// remove now empty special_tag
$foo->parentNode->removeChild($foo);

// output
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

Will result in something like

```
<html><body>
    <p>Some content</p>
        <p>Some more content</p>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code as well, I'm sure others will appreciate it, and I'll also say, it's probably a much smarter move heading towards DOM than relying as heavily as I have on preg functions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex to parse XML/HTML is not recommended. Use a **[DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)** parser instead.